# using kiwi viewer in ios app to view a 3D model

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am building an ios application in which I get a `ply` file from a server and want to view
it on my application using `kiwi viewer` , I need a help on how to do that exactly and where 
can I download the related files.
I have searched the web on it but did not get anything specific on the way of doing that and I got confused with files that should be attached to my project and the libraries also.
please I need help as soon as possible.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@flashdisk what version of ves / kiwi viewer you are using? The current version of VES can load the ply files. I am about to merge another branch that intend to fix some other issues as well.